# some wrong with CodeIgniter $this->load->view

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function admin($page = "admin")
{   

    $data['title'] = "admin";
    $data['menu'] = "admin";


    $this->load->view('tpl/header_admin',$data);
    $this->load->view('admin/'.$page,$data);

}
```

this is what i'm trying to do , header and content page , but i don't know why it's not working , if i do

```
public function admin($page = "admin")
{   

    $data['title'] = "admin";
    $data['menu'] = "admin";

    $this->load->view('tpl/header_admin',$data);

}
```

OR

```
public function admin($page = "admin")
{   

    $data['title'] = "admin";
    $data['menu'] = "admin";

    $this->load->view('admin/'.$page,$data);

}
```

it will all working , i can see the content in admin or header , but if i put two load->view together , it will only show $this->load->view('admin/'.$page,$data); header just won't show

This is what CI website said what should do :

```
$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
```

i don't see the different

BTW: if i visit /admin , header won't show , but if i visit /admin/list , it will show ...

first time this happen to me , why ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
<?php
public function admin($page = "admin")
{   

    $data['title'] = "admin";
    $data['menu'] = "admin";


    $data['header'] = $this->load->view('tpl/header_admin',$data,TRUE);//takes contains as string
    $this->load->view('admin/'.$page,$data);

}
```

And Inside your view admin/admin.php

```
if (isset($header))
{
    echo $header;
}
//Then other codes
```

`$data['header'] = $this->load->view('tpl/header_admin',$data,TRUE);`  This statement takes contains of `tpl/header_admin.php` as string with html tags.

Comment: public function view($page = 'home')
{
  if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
    {
        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}

this is what CI said .. i'm doing the same ... how is not working ..

Answer (score 0):

the function $this->load->view()
will output a HTML header. so u cannot output header twice.
the correct way is 
controller file

```
    public function admin($page = "admin")
    {   
        $data['title'] = "admin";
        $data['menu'] = "admin";
        $this->load->view('admin/index'.$page,$data);
    }
```

view file admin/index.php

```
    <html>
    <?php include '../tpl/header_admin.php' ?>
    template context.....
    </html>
```

This is the way of using the template file pieces

Comment: $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

this is what CI said .. i don't see the different

Comment: anyway, if you use Include in your template files, that will be much more flexible and more faster . if you want know why it is not working, please post the template code.